# How do I print in mirror image

Tags: printing

I want to print some iron-ons (like for t-shirts) which requires printing the document in reverse (aka mirror image). Does anyone know a way to do this in Ubuntu 11.10? As far as I know, my printer does not have the function built in.

Comment: What sort of document are you trying to print?  The application you're using might have support for transforming the image itself.

Comment: 1st off....what kind of printer do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be easily done from lp/lpr command line: check `file:///usr/share/cups/doc-root/help/options.html#MIRROR` (available [online](https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html#MIRROR)) on your system.

> The `-o mirror` option flips each page along the vertical axis to
>   produce a mirrored image:
>
> ```
> lp -o mirror filename
> lpr -o mirror filename
> ```
>
> This is typically used when printing on T-shirt transfer media or
>   sometimes on transparencies.

Comment: To save a step for anyone who finds this, the command is `lp -o mirror filename
`